# Rewrite rule for magento store view

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, magento-1.9

i have a question about .htaccess redirection rule. Namely, i have two store views in magento: english and swedish. I want to write rule in .htaccess that when user type in this address in browser url bar www.example.com/se to be redirected to https://example.com/se/
Can someone help me od give me some pointers for this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```